# Set-Location : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if someone could help me with the following script.  It works, but there are some things I am not sure why are happening.
I get the following error:

```
Set-Location : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument "path" to a non-null value.
At C:\APPS\Scripts\CreateFolder - Test.ps1:92 char:9
+         Set-Location $LabServer.Fullname
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

PowerShell says the error begins in:

```
Set-Location $LabServer
```

Also, if there is an empty line in the Textbox, it gets the following error

```
New-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At C:\APPS\Scripts\CreateFolder - Test.ps1:99 char:22
+             New-Item $Folder -type directory
+                      ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Here is the full script

```
# Load required assemblies
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

# Drawing form and controls
$CreateFolder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $CreateFolder.Text = "Create Folder"
    $CreateFolder.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
    $CreateFolder.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
    $CreateFolder.TopMost = $true
    $CreateFolder.MaximizeBox = $false
    $CreateFolder.MinimizeBox = $false
    $CreateFolder.ControlBox = $true
    $CreateFolder.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $CreateFolder.Font = "Segoe UI"


#======================== CASE NAME ========================#
# adding a label to my form
$label_message = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_message.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,8)
    $label_message.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,15)
    $label_message.Text = "Case Name"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($label_message)    
# CaseName    
    $CaseName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $CaseName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,30)
    $CaseName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,25)
    $CaseName.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($CaseName)


#======================== DROPBOX ========================#
$label_messageCombobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_messageCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,60)
    $label_messageCombobox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,15)
    $label_messageCombobox.Text = "Pick a Server"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($label_messageCombobox)    

$DropdownBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $DropdownBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,80)
    $DropdownBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,15)
    $DropdownBox.Height = 200
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($DropdownBox)
    
    $Servers = @("Lab Machine 50","Lab Machine 55")


    foreach($Server in $Servers){
        $DropdownBox.Items.Add($Server)
    }

Function Get-Server{
    $SelectedServer = $DropdownBox.SelectedItem.ToString()

    if($SelectedServer -eq "Lab Machine 50") {
        $LabServer = Set-Location "\\Server50\K$"
    }
    elseif($SelectedServer -eq "Lab Machine 55") {
        $LabServer = Set-Location "\\Server55\K$"
    }


}


#======================== INPUTBOX ========================#
$label_message2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_message2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,110)
    $label_message2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,15)
    $label_message2.Text = "Custodian Names"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($label_message2)    
    
# Inputbox    
    $Inputbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $Inputbox.Multiline = $True;
    $Inputbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,130)
    $Inputbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
    $Inputbox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($Inputbox)
    

# add a button ti create folder
$button_ClickMe = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_ClickMe.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,120)
    $button_ClickMe.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,32)
    $button_ClickMe.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_ClickMe.Text = "Create Folders Now!!!"
    $button_ClickMe.Add_Click({Get-Server})
    $button_ClickMe.Add_Click({
        

        Set-Location $LabServer
        New-Item $CaseName.Text -type directory
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        Set-Location ($LabServer.Text + $CaseName.Text)

        $button_ClickMe.Text = "Folders were created"
        ForEach ($Folder in $Inputbox.lines) {
            New-Item $Folder -type directory
            }
    })
    $CreateFolder.Controls.Add($button_ClickMe)


# show form
$CreateFolder.Add_Shown({$CreateFolder.Activate()})
[void] $CreateFolder.ShowDialog()
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path you provide for Set-Location is empty or does not exist, I would recommend to first use a statement to test if the path is actually present before executing code on it:

```
if (!(Test-path -path $($LabServer) ))
    Write-warning -message "$($LabServer) does not exist."
    break
}
else {
    #Do the rest of your code
}
```